# How to listen to some Twitter Account with linkToTwitter (C#)

Tags: c#, twitter, streaming

How to get the **linkToTwitter** to listen to other account (for example @Bloomberg)?

I've managed to build the full example of listen to twitter, populated the **"ScreenName"** with **@Bloomberg**, **but for some reason it "listen" only to my account (and react to tweets there)**  - the account I've created the tokens with.

**Is it possible to set a 3rd party twitter account (not me) to listen to (in streaming mode)? an d if not is there other framework you have experience with that does that?**

Answer (score 0):

Try including the screenName in the linq query:

```
var statusTweets = (from strm in twitterContext.Streaming
                    where strm.Type == StreamingType.User
                    && strm.ScreenName == "Bloomberg"
                    select strm)
                    .StartAsync(async strm =>
                    {
                        string message =
                            string.IsNullOrEmpty(strm.Content) ?
                                "Keep-Alive" : strm.Content;


                        Console.WriteLine(
                            (count + 1).ToString() +
                            ". " + DateTime.Now +
                            ": " + message + "\n");
                    });
```